# Django Dynamic Admin Site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to create a dynamic admin site, that based on if the field is blank or not will show that field.  So I have a model that has a set number of fields, but for each individual entry will not contain all of the fields in my model and I want to exclude based on if that field is blank. I posted this question with a lot less detail earlier, and it got put on hold, and so I posted a new question with a lot more detail.

I  have a unique bridge identifier, that correlates to each bridge, and then all of the various different variables that describe the bridge.

However, not every bridge is the same and I have a lot more variables that I would like to include in my model but for now I am just testing on two : prestressed_concrete_deck and reinforced_concrete_coated_bars.  What I want is to dynamically create the admin site to not display the prestressed_concrete_deck variable if that field is blank.  So instead of displaying all of the variables on the admin site, I want to only display those variables if that bridge has that part, and to not display anything if the field is blank.

Another possible solution to the problem would be to get that unique identifier over to my admins.py.  I cant figure out either how to get that individual key over as then I could query in the admins.py.  If i knew how to access the bridgekey, I could just query in my admins.py dynamically.  So how would I access the brkey for that entry in my admins.py (Something like BridgeModel.brkey ?)

I have tried several different things in my admin.py and have tried the comments suggestion of overwriting the get_fields() method in my admin class, but I am probably syntactically wrong and I am kind of confused what the object it takes exactly is.  Is that the actual entry?  Or is that the individual field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a previous method suggested of overriding the get_fields method.  This method did not work at all originally because I was using Django 1.6.2 version and this did not support overriding the get_fields method.  I upgraded to 1.7 , and overriding the get_fields worked

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I have understood your problem.

But in case I did and you just want to display only not null fields in your template. I suggest to hard code your query, in case you have to make joins, that interrogate your database in the `views.py` (`Bridge.objects.raw(query)`). After that you can send the result that you got to the html file as parameters and develop a javascript function to display or hide the field based on the contents of the parameters.

Comment: That is exactly my problem.  So if a field is left null or blank, I do not want to display it.  I was thinking of switching to django forms, but those have less security and would require a lot more work which is why I would really like to use the admin site.  Is there any previous documentation on incorporating html and javascript for the admin site explicitly?  I see documentation on the forms page but not on the admin site which is my goal.

Comment: You can add your js file  to  the inner  Media class of your admin class or another possible solution is to  oveeride the admin template and add your code javascript